using Open XML SAX technology, freeze the first line (title)
I am creating an Excel file with a large amount of data, for this reason I had to choose SAX technology, but I can’t find examples anywhere of how to freeze the first row so that when scrolling it remains at the top, I found many examples of how this is done, but it’s all in DOM technology
I found an example in the DOM, but technologies cannot be mixed, otherwise the meaning of using SAX is lost

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The solution was this block of code:
            OpenXmlWriter writer = OpenXmlWriter.Create(openXmlPart: work_sheet_part);
            writer.WriteStartElement(elementObject: new Worksheet());//начало рабочего листа

            SheetDimension sheet_dimension = new()
            {
                Reference = title_range
            };
            writer.WriteElement(sheet_dimension);
            writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetViews());
            writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetView() { WorkbookViewId = 0 });

            Pane pane = new()
            {
                VerticalSplit = 1,
                HorizontalSplit = 0,
                TopLeftCell = "A2",
                ActivePane = PaneValues.BottomLeft,
                State = PaneStateValues.Frozen
            };

            Selection selection = new Selection()
            {
                Pane = PaneValues.BottomLeft,
                ActiveCell = "A2",
                SequenceOfReferences = new ListValue<StringValue>() { InnerText = "A2" }
            };
            writer.WriteElement(pane);
            writer.WriteElement(selection);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();

